# How to (de)serialize DateTime objects as ISO8601 using Jackson 2.0?

Tags: java, jackson

I'd like to know whether it is possible to [de]serialize a Joda `DateTime` object into a ISO8601 `String` using Jackson without creating a custom `JsonSerializer<DateTime>`.

Surely this is a common enough function that is built into the library somewhere? The closest I could find is a `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`, but this seems to only apply to `Date` objects.

**EDIT:**

I found [this class](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601DateFormat.html): `ISO8601DateFormat`, but when I try the following code I don't get an ISO8601 string:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(DateTime.now());
```

Looks like Jackson doesn't treat Date and DateTime objects equally.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up writing a custom serializer for ISO8601 DateTime strings.

Comment: If you don't mind, it would be nice if you could spell out the answer as to what the custom serializer entailed and how you wired it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like [you should be able to do this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling):

```
// Set the date format to the desired (in this case, ISO8601)
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().setDateFormat(myDateFormat);

// or, as of Jackson 1.8, use
ObjectMapper#withDateFormat(myDateFormat)
```

since

> Starting with version 1.4, Jackson offers some support for Joda Time data types: basically, its `DateTime` can be automatically serialized/deserialized similar to how `java.util.Date` is handled.

The current API call is:

```
.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Comment: Now why isn't there a default ISO8601 DateFormat? >:|

Comment: Also, I think some of those methods are no longer in the 2.0 API. Looks like you need to use `ObjectMapper#setDateFormat`. Though this doesn't really help, because I still need to make my own ISO8601-compliant DateFormat.